# Expression in Access involving dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-access

I have written the following formular in Excel to calculate the year a person will be 18 by 1st September based on their DoB (in cell F2).  It seems to work ok in Excel:

```
=IF(MONTH(F2)<8,YEAR(DATE(YEAR(F2)+18,MONTH(F2),DAY(F2))),YEAR(DATE(YEAR(F2)+18,MONTH(F2),DAY(F2)))+1)
```

I need to change the formular so it works as an expression in Access and have converted it as follows (DoB is their date of birth which is a Date/Time field):

```
=iIF(Month([DoB])<8,Year(DATE(YEAR([DoB])+18,Month([DoB]),Day([DoB]))),Year(DATE(Year([DoB])+18,Month([DoB]),Day([DoB]))+1)
```

However, it won't work and keeps saying the expression has a function containing the wrong number of arguments.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an odd number of brackets... 12 ('s and 11 )'s. I suspect you just need a final closing bracket on the end?

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I have added the final bracket and changed it to: =IIf(Month([DoB])<8,(Year(DATE(YEAR([DoB])+18,Month([DoB]),Day([DoB])))),(Year(DATE(Year([DoB])+18,Month([DoB]),Day([DoB]))+1))

Comment: ...but it's still not working.  Any ideas?  Does everything else look ok?

Comment: "not working", in the same way with the same error or has it changed?

Comment: Still the same error message yes.